# Incorrect syntax near '0'. (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

When I execute this procedure below it return me `Incorrect syntax near '0'`. I have no idea why.

Mistake is localized in `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 43`. Can you tell me what is wrong? Thank you for advance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PV_SaveCategory] 
(
    @AccountID              BIGINT,
    @LocationID             BIGINT,
    @CategoryName           NVARCHAR(100),
    @ParentID               BIGINT,
    @ExternalCategoryID     BIGINT
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ExecSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ExecSQL = N'
DECLARE @CategoryID INT, @Level INT
SELECT @CategoryID = Id FROM [DB].[dbo].[Category_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @AccountID, 0) + '] WHERE @ExternalCategoryID = ExternalID
SELECT @Level = Level+1 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Category_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @AccountID, 0) + '] WHERE @ParentID = Id

IF @CategoryID IS NULL
BEGIN
INSERT
    INTO [DB].[dbo].[Category_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @AccountID, 0) + ']
            (
                 Name
                ,LocationID
                ,IsDeleted
                ,Level
                ,ParentCategoryID
                ,Main
                ,SubCategory1
                ,SubCategory2
                ,SubCategory3
                ,SubCategory4
                ,CategoryPath
                ,ExternalID
            )
            VALUES
            (
                @CategoryName,
                @LocationID,
                0,
                CASE WHEN @ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @Level END,
                @ParentID,
                0,
                1,
                2,
                4,
                ''test'',
                @ExternalCategoryID
            )
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[Category_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @AccountID, 0) + '] SET
                Level = CASE WHEN @ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @Level END,
                0,
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                ''test2'',
            Where @CategoryID = Id AND @ParentID = ParentCategoryID
    END'

    print @ExecSQL

    EXECUTE sp_executeSQl @ExecSQL, N'@AccountID BIGINT, @LocationID BIGINT, @CategoryName NVARCHAR(100), @ParentID BIGINT, @ExternalCategoryID BIGINT',
             @AccountID = @AccountID, @LocationID = @LocationID, @CategoryName = @CategoryName, @ParentID = @ParentID, @ExternalCategoryID = @ExternalCategoryID

END;
```

Comment: you have 12 fields defined in you insert command and only 11 values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see 2 problems.

1. you have 12 fields defined in you insert command and only 11 values
2. the update statement has no column names (except for the first one)

it should be like this :

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[Category_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @AccountID, 0) + '] 
SET  Level = CASE WHEN @ParentID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @Level END,
     field1 = 0,
     field2 = 1,
     field3 = 2,
     field4 = 3,
     field5 = 4,
     field6 = 'test2'
 Where @CategoryID = Id 
 AND   @ParentID = ParentCategoryID
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Update statement is not complete after assign value to Level other **left hand side column names are missing**